# Vega-lite Multiple aggregations in Transforms

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I want to implement two diff aggregations in a transform as they have different groupby conditions, but it seems not possible with vega-lite

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": {

      {"response":200,"request":"/ST"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/ST"},
      {"response":200,"request":"/PP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/PP"},
      {"response":200,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":200,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":500,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":503,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":503,"request":"/CP"},
      {"response":503,"request":"/CP"}

  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{
       "op": "count",
       "as": "response_count"
      }],
      "groupby": ["response","request"]
    },
    {
      "aggregate": [{
       "op": "count",
       "as": "response_c"
      }],
      "groupby": ["request"]
    }
     ],

     {"mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "response_count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "zero"},
        "y": {"field": "request", "type": "nominal"},
        "color": {"field": "response", "type": "nominal"}}
}
```

Is there any way of achieving this ? Are multiple aggregations like this supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiple aggregations like this are supported, but your chart has undefined fields in the end because you have have not referenced them in your aggregations. You start with this data:

```
[
  {"response": 200, "request": "/ST"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/ST"},
  {"response": 200, "request": "/PP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/PP"},
  {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
  {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"}
]
```

The first aggregation groups by `"response"` and `"request"`, and adds `"response_count"` in each group, which looks like this:

```
[
  {"response": 200, "request": "/ST", "response_count": 1},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/ST", "response_count": 1},
  {"response": 200, "request": "/PP", "response_count": 1},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/PP", "response_count": 1},
  {"response": 200, "request": "/CP", "response_count": 2},
  {"response": 500, "request": "/CP", "response_count": 6},
  {"response": 503, "request": "/CP", "response_count": 3},
]
```

Your second aggregation takes this, groups by `"request"`, and adds `"response_c"` in each group, which looks like this:

```
[
  {"request": "/ST", "response_c": 2},
  {"request": "/PP", "response_c": 2},
  {"request": "/CP", "response_c": 3},
]
```

Notice that any fields you don't reference in the aggregation are dropped.

Your specification then refers to fields that no longer exist in the dataset, which results in a blank chart.

You could fix this by specifying in the second aggregation what you want to happen with the fields that are dropped; for example, you could keep the sum of "response_count" and the minimum of "response" ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAE4kAOA9gHbGFkBMADDwDRQGARyLF4ZSAHoAygBVIAX35VqtBsRbtOqAKx9B9QqJITU0+UpXUaRzWw7cDQ42LNQpABU9XVGdUwOOmD6Ai4m4pJePsp+thpajqi8YUYR7tIAwjHWNgH22k6pIm5R2b42aHaJwaGGJaZlOXFVCUFkdeGl5lLlsZX5NR3Oad0efblq1e16Iw2RPRMtgzMhc66Ni80D04WzxRsL49t5u0lrAMz1hxm9J1Nte5fX6U0Vp4-n+lddm8dKfgAulR+lB4HRYOwAGbMOgAWzIlDULUgsAA5miGGiEMFyLRmIxJABjZj4VgSQywUjmT6EAD6JLJEkUgMmGEgmNJjAARgBPRFnTgvUrA6igmgo9GYwjY+C4lq2AnE0nkyCU6kuAocBnvHZK8zEfAIwxQgCWhFw0EktIZKopUCp1sC2ltTN1p31UDhptYaqgZotVppzsc6qdWs4iharJRnPwPP5qHIo0aoowUYgMcwcNgdAA1pJubm1VRIIRWCToD60WR0OyAB61yABy3hmqu1WGeC8xjBSCiSHwU2IIdYIVQcSwIkF8wAL0IdGY7sgiaqLaDv0iXZ7fdYzG9rDwy5JuFhTfXbfa297kj3B6PGbAUcUQA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"response": 200, "request": "/ST"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/ST"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/PP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/PP"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "response_count"}],
      "groupby": ["response", "request"]
    },
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "count", "as": "response_c"},
        {"op": "sum", "field": "response_count", "as": "response_count"},
        {"op": "min", "field": "response", "as": "response"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["request"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "response_count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "zero"},
    "y": {"field": "request", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"field": "response", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Better in this particular case might be to leave out the second aggregation altogether, in which case the second aggregation essentially happens visually via stacking of the bars ([editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJAE4kAOA9gHbGFkBMADDwDRQGARyLF4ZSAHoAygBVIAX35VqtBsRbtOqAKx9B9QqJITU0+UpXUaRzWw7cDQ42LNQpABU9XVGdUwOOmD6Ai4m4pJePsp+thpajqi8YUYR7tIAwjHWNgH22k6pIm5R2b42aHaJwaGGJaZlOXFVCUFkdeGl5lLlsZX5NR3Oad0efblq1e16Iw2RPRMtgzMhc66Ni80D04WzxRsL49t5u0lrAMz1hxm9J1Nte5fX6U0Vp4-n+lddm8dKfgAulR+lB4HRYOwAGbMOgAWzIlDULUgsAA5miGGiEMFyLRmIxJABjZj4VgSQywUjmT6EAD6JLJEkUgMmGEgmNJjAARgBPRFnTgvUrA6iKKisqiQOGwOgAa0k3NlkFykEIrBJ0AAlqw0WR0OyAB76yBQrWEXDQSS0hmk8kqsG8xjBSCiSHwLWID1YIVQcSwIkK8wAL0IdGY70w-NQtDNFqtNJuDsg8CdLtYzDhOrwkagJNwsJNcct1sChUMqedkgzWdYOfFEHFiiAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"response": 200, "request": "/ST"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/ST"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/PP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/PP"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 200, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 500, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"},
      {"response": 503, "request": "/CP"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "response_count"}],
      "groupby": ["response", "request"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "response_count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "zero"},
    "y": {"field": "request", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"field": "response", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But how do I keep the former ' response_count' field? I need it to calculate a percentage using both fields( response_count/response_c). Or how can these aggregations work independently?

Comment: You might be looking for the [joinaggregate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/joinaggregate.html), which joins the aggregation results to the original data.